Differential of a Smooth Map Notation in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds
I am reworking through Chapter 3 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, and am looking at proposition 3.8:

Let M be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, $p \in M, v \in T_pM$. If $f,g \in C^{\infty}(M)$ agree on some neighborhood of p, then $vf=vg$.

They provide a proof, however my question arose from the path of proof I was attempting. Here it is:
Assume the above information. Consider the smooth identity map $Id:M\to M$. Looking at the differential;
$d(Id)_p(v)(f)=v(f \circ Id)=vf$
Now is where I am slightly unsure if my idea works. I want to say that, since $f(p)=g(p)$, we have $vf=vf(p)=vg(p)=vg$
However, my confusion I suppose is stemming from the notation of our point p in the differential. When we say in general that $dF_p(v)(f)=v(f\circ F)$, are we inherently assuming $f(F(p))?$
I know Lee usually notes when we are abusing notation and what not, but I couldn't find if this were the case or not.

Think about the case $M = \mathbb{R}^n$. $vf = Df(p)v$, is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$. Hence $vf = vg$ if $f$ and $g$ agree on some curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, $\gamma'(0) = v$ since $Df(p)v = \frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))|_{t = 0}$. The exact same reasoning applies to general $M$.

It is an important hypothesis that $f$ and $g$ agree on a neighbourhood of the point $p$, instead of just at the point $p$ itself. For example, $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 0$ are two functions (in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$) which agree at the point $p = 0$, but do not have $df_0 = dg_0$.
It is a standard abuse of notation in differential geometry to write expressions like $v(f \circ F)$; you are correct in assuming this is a computation taking place `at p', because the tangent vector $v$ lives in the tangent space $T_p M$ to $M$ at the point $p$. The point of this proposition is that $v(f \circ F)$ depends on more than just the value of $f(F(p))$; in order to take a derivative in the $v$ direction, we need to know what $f(F(p))$ looks like in a neighbourhood. Conversely, this is all we need. If two functions $f, g$ are identical on a neighbourhood of $p$, then they have identical derivative at $p$.

Thanks for the speedy reply; I appreciate that example. Is the idea that we have $df_0=dg_0$, but not the stronger $df=dg$? At 0 these differentials seemingly agree, so perhaps that is what you meant unless I am misunderstanding (very possible, ha).

It's not the case that $df_0 = dg_0$. We can think of $dg_0 = 0$ while $df_0 = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right\rvert_{x = 0}$. So if you took the tangent vector $v = \gamma'(0)$ where $\gamma(t) = t$, for example, then you would have $df_0 \gamma'(0) = \frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(0)) = \frac{d}{dt} f(t) = \frac{d}{dt} t = 1$, while $dg_0 \gamma'(0) = \frac{d}{dt} g(\gamma(0)) = \frac{d}{dt} g(t) = \frac{d}{dt} 0 = 0$.

I have seemingly fallen into a rabbit hole of confusion, lol. Ok. f is essentially the identity function, and g sends all of R to a point. So I think intuitively I am seeing why the differential of f at 0 is identity and why the differential of g at 0 is the 0 function. However the computation for this is not clicking for me. What am I doing incorrectly when I evaluate:
$df_0(v)(h)$, where $h(x)=x, h'(0)=v$ Then $v(h \circ f)=?$ my instinct is to evaluate v$(h(f(0))$ now but this gives $v(0)$.

First note that we should be composing $f \circ h$, not $h \circ f$; $h$ is a function from an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ into the manifold $M$, while $f$ is a (smooth) function $M \to \mathbb{R}$. The definition of $df_0(v)$ [note no $h$ here; $df_0$ is a function that eats a tangent vector at 0 and spits out a number] is then $\left. \frac{d}{dx} f(h(x))\right\rvert_{x=0}$. I don't recall exactly how Lee sets it up. It is a good exercise to show that for general (smooth) $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and with $\gamma(t) = t$ defining $v = \gamma'(0)$, then $(df_0)(v) = f'(0)$.

If f is our smooth function $f:M \to R$, then h would need to be $h \in C^{\infty}(R)$ I thought, since then $df_0(v)(h)=v(h \circ f)$ and $h \circ f \in C^{\infty}(M)$

A tangent vector is defined to be (the equivalence class of) $h'(0)$, where $h$ is a smooth map $I \to M$, for $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ an open interval containing 0. We think of $h(t)$ as tracing a curve on the manifold $M$, and $h'(0)$ being the tangent to that curve at the point $h(0)$. Thus we have a map $h \colon \mathbb{R} \to M$, and a map $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$, and the natural composition is $f \circ h \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I'm not fully sure what is meant by the notation $df_0(v)(h)$; already $df_0(v)$ is a real number.

I mean ok in our original case everything is running from R to R so this is fine. I think I was caught up on the fact that for v a tangent vector of R, we know its represented by d/dx, and that for $v(h(f(x)))$ we evaluate x=0 at the end. So $v(h(f(x)))=\frac{d}{dx}(h(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(x)=1$

As far as that notation, it shows up first on page 55 of Lee if you have a copy. The differential of F at p is said to be defined as $dF_p:T_pM \to T_{F(p)}N$ and he says that $dF_p(v)$ is the derivation at F(p) that acts on $f \in C^{\infty}(N)$ by the rule $dF_p(v)(f)=v(f \circ F)$

I see. Lee is talking about the differential of a map between manifolds $F \colon M \to N$. In essence, this is the same object as the differential of a smooth function, although we usually make some identifications under the hood to make the notation a bit cleaner in the case of $N = \mathbb{R}$.

I was starting to catch on that you were going with N=R, haha. In that case yes $dF_p(v)$ is a real number already because elements of $T_{F(p)}R$ are just that.
